# What's the correct jQuery selector for this? I want to get all tr with attr x, which are directly beneath (same level) given tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm currently working on something like a tree, and I want to be able to fold/unfold children. I guess the most easy way to get this is by using nested lists, but I can't use them because I don't have access to the HTML code. This is the relevant simplified HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr rel="1"><td><a href="#" id="fold">fold</a> item 1</td></tr>
        <tr rel="2"><td><a href="#" id="fold">fold</a> item 1.1</td></tr>
        <tr rel="2"><td><a href="#" id="fold">fold</a> item 1.2</td></tr>
        <tr rel="1"><td>item 2</td></tr>
        <tr rel="1"><td><a href="#" id="fold">fold</a> item 3</td></tr>
        <tr rel="2"><td><a href="#" id="fold">fold</a> item 3.1</td></tr>
        <tr rel="3"><td>item 3.1.1</td></tr>
        <tr rel="3"><td>item 3.1.2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, no nested items, but there are 'levels' available, so I guess it should be possible to do what I have in mind. The fold/unfold part is working, f.e. when I click fold on item 1, items with rel >= 2 are hidden. But that's not what I want; I only want to fold the items which rel is higher than the one where I clicked fold, and want to hide all of them until I reach an element which rel is lower or equal to the current rel.

For example, when I click fold in item 1, item 1.1 and 1.2 should be hidden, but item 3.1 should stay visible.

Is there anyone that can help me getting started? Thanks.

Bjorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you can achieve this with a single selector. This is my approach: http://jsfiddle.net/RrnDG/1/ Note that i changed your `id="fold"` to `class="fold"`, since having multiple IDs with the same value is invalid. An ID is meant to be unique.

What i am doing here is (basically):

- get level of the clicked row
- traverse all following rows. for each do:

  - check if level is higher (e.g. deeper nested); if true, toggle visibility, otherwise abort traversing

Comment: Thanks, this is working, I was trying to solve things way to difficult! :)

Comment: Small note: I changed your `fold`-ID to a class, since an ID has to be unique and cannot be used multiple times. I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: I already saw it in the code, fixed it already (but not on SO), thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```
$("#fold").click(function()
{
    var _current = $(this).parent().parent();
    var _level = _current.attr('rel');

    _current.nextAll().each(function()
    {
        if($(this).attr('rel') > _level){
            $(this).hide();
        }else{
            // Nested children stopped here, we don't continue
            return false;
        }
    });        
});
```